# Same class (share data)

Tags: android, textview

I created an AlertDialog(edit text), but later I want put the value inserted to an array:

```
void goToPage(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString();
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(value);
    // Do something with value!
    }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
    }
    });
    alert.show();           
}
```

In the same class I've this array:

```
array[20]
```

In the same class, I can't use value2 because has not shared.

How share a data inside a method to entire class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can share data from a method to an entire class by passing it into a globally scoped variable. So:

```
public class MyClass {
int num; //now this is global

//....everything else


}
```

Make sure you understand how scope works in Java. Scope changes when you are in methods and loops. But global variables can always be accessed from anywhere in the class. The exception to this rule gets weird in situations like this:

```
public class MyClass {
int num; //now this is global

    public MyClass(){
        num = 1;
    }
    public void access(int num) {
        num = 5;
    }
    public void printOut() {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

}
```

Running it:

```
MyClass something = new MyClass();
something.access(8);
something.printOut();
```

The value of int would still be `1` because the other instance (in access()) of `num` was local, meaning that the global `num` did not know it existed. They are different. That is what the `this` keyword is for. But I won't get into it. You can definitely do the research :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use the array[20] in the "onClick" function